# Aggregate ad clicks and views

Tags: mysql

Given the following table, which tracks clicks and views per ad campaign:

```
record_id     advert_id     type
-----------------------------------
1             100           click
2             102           click
3             100           view
4             100           view
5             102           view
6             100           view
7             101           view
8             101           click
```

Is it possible to aggregate the clicks and views with a single query, i.e. so that it looks like this:

```
advert_id     clicks      views
-------------------------------
100           1           3
101           1           1
102           1           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by  `advert_id` and use a conditional aggregation

```
select advert_id, 
       sum(type = 'click') as clicks,
       sum(type = 'view') as views
from your_table
group by advert_id
```

Answer (score 1):

- We can `GROUP BY` on `advert_id`. This will allow you to aggregate results for a specific `advert_id` into a single row.
- Now, we can utilize [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression on `type` to conditionally check whether its value is `click` or `type` and accordingly [`Count()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) the clicks, and views respectively.

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  advert_id
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'click' THEN 1 END) AS clicks, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'view' THEN 1 END) AS views 
FROM  your_table 
GROUP BY advert_id
```