# Group value mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have a table log with format [prodName, status]

An example set be:

```
| ProdName |  Status
|-----------------------
|  AXD1    | 100
|  BL1     | 100
|  AXD2    | 300
|  BL2     | 300
|  AXD1    | 300
|  AXD2    | 100
|  BL1     | 100
|  BL1     | 100
```

I will the result group by status where 100 is success and 300 not. So the result like this.

```
| ProdName |  Success | Not
|-----------------------
|  AXD1    | 1        | 1
|  BL1     | 3        | 0
|  AXD2    | 1        | 1
|  BL2     | 0        | 1
```

Comment: It is a conditional aggregation problem using `CASE .. WHEN` and `GROUP BY`. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53246323/2469308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `case` expressions to find if a row was a success or not, and then count them:

```
SELECT   ProdName,
         COUNT(CASE Status WHEN 100 THEN 1 END) AS "Success",
         COUNT(CASE Status WHEN 300 THEN 1 END) AS "Not Success"
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY ProdName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
  ProdName,
  sum(Status = 100) Success,
  sum(Status = 300) `Not`
from Log
group by ProdName
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHw6P4hdtkELuQmcHtWjVY/1).
Results:

```
| ProdName | Success | Not |
| -------- | ------- | --- |
| AXD1     | 1       | 1   |
| AXD2     | 1       | 1   |
| BL1      | 3       | 0   |
| BL2      | 0       | 1   |
```